# Non negative function at a point is less the the integral of the function

Tags: calculus, integration, upper-lower-bounds

I have a function
$$
f(x):\mathbb{R}^n->\mathbb{R}
$$
which is **non negative** on the whole space.

Can I say the following statment:
$$
\forall x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n \ , \ f(x_0) \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x) \ dx
$$
I think its true by intuation: The function is non negative and so integrating is like accumulating mass.

But I couldn't find a proof anywhere online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be answered by many counter-examples from probability; just because the probability integrates to $1$ doesn't mean that the density function must be less than one. Consider for example the pdf of the $\chi^2_1$ distribution:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\le0\\\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}&x\gt 0\end{cases}$$

We have that:

$$\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1$$

But $f\to+\infty$ as $x\to 0^+$, and attains values greater than $1$; e.g., $f(10^{-4})\approx40\gt1$.

With regards to intuition, I'll say that a very thin slice is integrated to a very small value - our function here blows up to $\infty$, yet in integration the region where it is large is so slim that the integral is small...

Comment: I see.
So in which cases one can say a function is less then its integral everywhere?

Comment: Your question is very broad, @OriKenig . I can take any function you give me, append to its definition a step function of arbitrarily high value and arbitrarily small support, and this would still leave the function integrable - in fact, I can rig this so that the integral is unchanged - but the function could exceed its integral as much as I wish